# Hold down flaps of plastic sheets on exterior shed

Tags: weather-resistant

I have a new wood shed for storing firewood. One problem is that rain and snow can blow into the shed and get the wood wet, so I am thinking of hanging some thick plastic sheeting over the front of the shed to protect from water. The problem is how to secure the flaps.

One obvious strategy is to use hook and eye. You install eyes in the plastic and put hooks in the bottom of the shed and the eyes are put on the hooks to hold the sheet down. The problem is that to put eyes in the plastic properly I would need either or grommet punch or I would have to fool around with a peening hammer, which could get messy.

So, I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: you can get a grommet starter kit from harbor fright for under $10, not a big or bad investment. I like magnets for securing sheet plastic; they can stick to other magnets (glued in place) or nails. A roll of super magnets is only a few bucks from ebay.

Answer (score 1):

Grommet kits sold in hardware stores (Ace, Home Depot, your local independent store) will generally include everything you need: grommets, punch, and anvil. E.g. something like this:
[image]

That said, even heavy duty plastic may not last more than a year or two outdoors. Between wind and UV, it'll get torn up pretty quickly. You might find that oilcloth or similar is a better choice if you're looking for covering.

And *that* said, you might want to reconsider whether it's worth doing all this work. Covering the sides of the shed will interfere with air flow which helps dry the wood. And in my experience, even on a windy day, the amount of moisture that actually gets on wood that's under cover is reasonably minimal. It doesn't soak in very far, and it dries out pretty quickly.

I would go through a heating season or even two first, to see whether the weather is really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo privacy screens will gravity hang, do the same thing, and look better than tarp/poly solutions.